# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: discord.py

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel' is the error I am getting. I have been looking around however, the answer still isn't clear. The code was working before, but now it is not. I don't think I made any changes to channel attribute.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if 'SJAY' in u:
        message = '{0.author.mention}, Did you know Sjay is a God?'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, message)

client.loop.create_task(change_stat())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I don't even see a 'str' variable here. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because before using it you changed its value into a string. Doing the following changes will resolve the issue:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if 'SJAY' in u:
        msg = '{0.author.mention}, Did you know Sjay is a God?'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

client.loop.create_task(change_stat())
client.run(TOKEN)
```